# AWS SQS SendMessage takes hundreds of seconds to complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am developing a web application where a HTTP request triggers a long background task. To decouple the HTTP request processing I am using AWS SQS. I enqueue the request to do the background processing when handling the HTTP request. The message is then picked up by background process which actually does the work. This way the latency of my application is kept low.

---

Recently I noticed worryingly high latencies when sending messages to SQS. I tried googling and the normal latency should be in [hundreds of milliseconds](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#Features.2C_functionality.2C_and_interfaces).

[image: newrelic external services monitoring]

The problem is the latency sometimes spikes over 130000 ms! The background processing actually takes less time than enqueuing the work.

I am using **Standard queue**, which I understand is a more of a best-effort service. Is this kind of latency common thing with AWS SQS? How can I proceed with debugging of this issue?

The messages are short JSONs containing the ID of the object which should be processed in background.

```json
{"type":"DO_BACKGROUND_WORK","ids":["123456"]}
```

The obvious reason could be networking issue between AWS and my server. However the SES endpoint does not have such latencies, nor the Rollbar error logging does.

The application is hosted in Europe (Contabo) but not in AWS. The CPU load is normal during the work, also the RAM usage is normal.

[image: new relic cpu and memory usage]

Comment: Where is the server? Is this code running on AWS like on an EC2 instance? Is the server's CPU spiking high during this time?

Comment: @MarkB I added the additional information to the question. The server is NOT in AWS, it is however in Europe. CPU and Memory usages are low. Also the disk usage is 4%.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? Hitting the same thing with some code running in Lambda. The SQS Send Message takes about 100 seconds, intermittently.

Comment: No solution sadly. I just moved the SendMessage operation to background task and live with occasional latencies.